# Is there anyway to save search results in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

This might be a newbie question but it really takes too long to search for certain things in IDA, when I close the app and save the database all my searches are gone and that's just frustrating.
I'm aware that I can copy and paste them all in text file but I prefer saving them in IDA itself.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [Mark Position](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/582.shtml) feature. (Jump -> Mark Position).

Comment: Hey @ExtremeCoders and thanks for the answer, but that's not even close to what i'm looking for, some searches contains hundreds of results and I have to check them manually but I won't be able to do that at once, so if I decided to close the app for any reason I won't be able to complete what I started.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a [script](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/367.shtml) for that.